# How to hide NavigationView Bar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

I cannot hide `NavigationView` bar. I tried both variants:

**Code 1:**

```
  public var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      MasterView()
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
  }
```

**Code 2:**

```
  public var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      MasterView()
    }
      .navigationBarHidden(true)
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Seems that the solution could be adding a title or removing the space from safe area.

The problem:

[image]

Solution 1:

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
```

Solution 2 (this seems be the best):

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
```

[image]

Comment: Weird, that we need to set a title to hide it... But works, thank you.

Comment: For me it worked just by adding `edgesIgnoringSafeArea `

Comment: Does it work on device rotation change. If i rotate p > l > p then there space appear i think it is related to geometry reader + navigation view

Comment: only `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])` work for me

Comment: In iOS 14, using .navigationBarHidden(true) is all I needed to make this work.

Comment: It worked BUT for some reason the view got moved also horizontally, so in case someone had the same issue, I fixed it by adding `.position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)`

Comment: Not working in iOS 15

Comment: .navigationBarHidden(true)
is enough for iOS 15.5

Answer (score 1):

> `navigationBarHidden` will be deprecated in a future.

Solution:

```
struct HiddenNavUIView: View {
  @State private var tabState: Visibility = .hidden
  
  var body: some View {
      NavigationStack {
        ScrollView {
          VStack(spacing: 12) {
            ForEach(1...50, id: \.self) { index in
              Text("Row \(index)")
              .frame(height: 32)
            }
          }
          .padding(15)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Hello")
        .toolbar(tabState, for: .navigationBar) // <- here
      }
  }
}
```